# Guard Band Reduction in 5G compared to 4G

Tags: rf, network, telecommunications

Why is there less guard band required for 5G as compared to 4G .For 4G guard band are defined to be 10% of bandwidth on each side while guard band for 5G are defined in 3GPP 38.101-2. For ex If we take 15 KHz SCS and 10 MHz bandwidth guard band for 4G would be \$10MHz*0.1*2 = 2MHz\$ while for 5G it would be \$312.5kHz*2=0.625MHz\$ which is a drastic improvement.
(i) Why was 10% of bandwidth was chosen as guard band for 4G?
(ii)How has it been reduced in 5G?

Comment: something to do with ratio of IF frequencies to carrier frequencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (i) Why was 10% of bandwidth was chosen as guard band for 4G?

That 10% was probably seen as a realistic value at the time. Realistic in the sense that it could be achieved with the available technology at the time.

> (ii)How has it been reduced in 5G?

Note that the 5G standard doesn't say anything about **how** to implement the system, instead it describes how the system should **behave**. So the 5G standard doesn't tell us **how** to reduce the guard band it just tells us what it needs to be.

Again the value is likely to be technology related. Technology has moved on so now we can have more processing power available to shape the signals such that a smaller guard band can be used.

The shape (over frequency) of a 4G or 5G baseband signal is determined by how much (digital) filtering is used. Obviously more complex filtering could result in a signal that is "cleaner" so that the distance between channels can be smaller and smaller guard bands can be used.

Comment: As far as I know 4G and 5G use the same waveform CP-OFDM so it should not depend on signal shape

Comment: I suggest that you look into OFDM and see how one OFDM isn't the same as another OFDM. OFDM just describes a way to modulate a signal to transfer data. It doesn't tell you how many bits to use, what the bandwith of your signal needs to be, what SNR you need etc. There are still many parameters that can be varied between two OFDM signals.

Comment: if the waveform construction (which might include calibrated nulling at RF) is not of adequate precision, then the DSP is in vain.